# Circuit with Hadamard on ancilla to calculate a specific function

Tags: quantum-computing

I am viewing this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHkfAC5Iu9I&list=PLmRxgFnCIhaMgvot-Xuym_hn69lmzIokg&index=29

My question is on the right side of the presentation, "Kernel as Interference" :
why having a such Hadamard ancilla qubit can help to calculate the above function ? Can we find in detail the explanation in a paper ? Why having the result |0> on the ancilla is intersting, and why are we discarding the |1> ?
I am very curious about how to find the "mental path" that has linked to this solution.